# viability of ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I'm porting three of my WP7 apps, that use my WCF SOAP Services to Android (so I can make some money for a change).  They don't like SOAP over there so I need to make a duplicate version of my WCF service methods to Restful services.

I created a simple working test service some months ago using the WCF REST Service Template 40(CS) template so that's one choice.  However I see a lot on the web about ASP.NET Web API using MVC 4.

My question is: Is this fully cooked and going to grow and prosper or is Microsoft going to get me all involved in this and then drop it like a hot potato after I've got a year in it.

Comment: With the release of Windows 8 VB6 will have support up until sometime in the late 2020s...

Comment: I'd be more worried about ongoing support for WCF REST than I would for ASP.NET Web API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would choose whatever got the job done that was supportable while being the least effort to implement. If I was on a level playing field I would run with the WebAPI mainly because it is very, very smooth. I would also version my API using versioned urls or content negotiation to insulate myself.

I can't speak for Microsoft, but in general they stand behind anything they have released as a fully supported product for quite some time. I'd expect the WebAPI to be supported at least as long as the platform. I don't see Microsoft dropping .NET support anytime soon and I would expect to see .NET 4.0 supported for the foreseeable future.

Comment: After looking things over more, the MVC part of the ASP.NET Web API scares me.  I view MVC as rigid and restrictive and it's a deep study.  I figure I could spend the next month completing my app or spend it studying the bowels of MVC.

Thanks for  your view.

Gary

Comment: The webAPI definitely isn't mvc -- you might be getting tripped up by the fact the are presenting it as an expansion of MVC sites typically. But it stands on it's head pretty well. Also, the microsoft MVC implementation is really more flexible than rigid. It ain't as pre-rolled as rails or django.